# How to solve error installing PyObjC in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, pip, pyobjc

I try to installing `PyObjC` using pip but still getting error

> `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-819f93sh/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-819f93sh/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
>            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-819f93sh/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/
>       Complete output (15 lines):
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-819f93sh/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
>           extra_link_args=['-framework', 'ScreenSaver']),
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-819f93sh/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/pyobjc_setup.py", line 392, in Extension
>           os_level = get_os_level()
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-819f93sh/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/pyobjc_setup.py", line 206, in get_os_level
>           pl = plistlib.readPlist('/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist')
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/plistlib.py", line 162, in readPlist
>           with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
>           return next(self.gen)
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/plistlib.py", line 120, in _maybe_open
>           with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
>       ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, unable to install pyobjc throwing same error as you. Let me know if you are able to install it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. [PyObjC can only be installed at MacOS X](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src/da944def921adcc7e91dc23b10bf2aec6d6b171b/pyobjc-core/setup.cfg#lines-33).

Comment: Yes, it is. There is no information about it on the doccumentation page. wasted much time on this.

Comment: How can I make the documentation clearer? BTW. I'll try to make the error clearer, the current error is not very user friendly.

Comment: @RonaldOussoren Add clear message(s) "PyObjC requires MacOS X" or "PyObjC is supported only on MacOS X" to the docs. I recommend the following places: [the repo](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src/default/): above "Supported Python versions" add a section "Supported OS (platform)". [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) and  [core@PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-core/); yes, I know PyPI shows "Operating System", seems it's not enough. [The docs](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): at the top of the section "Supported platforms".

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
git clone https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc
```

install it manually :
`python3 pyobjc/install.py` or `python2 pyobjc/install.py` or by going in the directory.